# Simulate button click Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, buttonclick

I am working on my project and I want to implement functionality when I click on toggle button and button is on (checked) the setInterval is called and it calls function "someFunction" to do stuff every 5 seconds.
When I click again on toggle button to switch it off I want to call clearInterval to stop "someFunction" from calling every 5 seconds.
The code works fine and I get my wanted result.

--app.ts--

```
let toggleButton: HTMLInputElement;
let interval;

toggleButton = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("toggle_switch");

toggleButton.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (target.checked) {
      try {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
          return someFunction();
        }, 5000);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  });
```

However, now I want to write test case for that, but I am a little bit stuck. Is this a right approach?

---app.test.ts---

```
import {toggleButton} from "./app";
jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.spyOn(global, "setInterval");

describe("Testing if interval is set or clear on button click", () => {
  test("When toggle switch is on", () => {
    toggleButton.click();
    expect(setInterval).toBeCalled();
  });
  test("When toggle switch is off", () => {
    toggleButton.click();
    expect(clearInterval).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: are the tests passing?

Comment: Do you have JSDOM configured, does your test understand what the `document` is?